# Working example for Graph Toolkit using SharePoint spfx, React and Get component with template

Tags: reactjs, templates, sharepoint, spfx, microsoft-graph-toolkit

I'm trying to make use of the Microsoft Graph Toolkit inside my SharePoint spfx web part solution, and more specifically the React version (@microsoft/mgt-react).

I've managed importing the packages, and also render the  control correctly.

However I am now trying to render  controls based on the result from a  control. Something like this:

```
const MyPerson = (props: MgtTemplateProps) => {
      const { person } = props.dataContext;
      return <Person userId={person.userPrincipalName}></Person>;
    }
```

And here is the  control:

```
      <Get resource={`/groups/${this.props.groupid}/members`}>
        <MyPerson template="value" />
      </Get>
```

Nothing is rendered out.
Could someone help me out fixing this?

Thanks!

UPDATED WORKING SAMPLE:

```
  public render(): React.ReactElement<IMemberListProps> {

const LoadingPerson = (props: MgtTemplateProps) => {
      return <div><Spinner size={SpinnerSize.large} label="Loading members..." /></div>;
    };

const MemberPerson = (props: MgtTemplateProps) => {
      const person = props.dataContext;
        return <div className={styles.memberRow}>
          <Person userId={person.userPrincipalName} view={PersonViewType.twolines} fetchImage={true} showPresence={true}
            personCardInteraction={PersonCardInteraction.hover} line2Property="mail"></Person></div>;
    };

    return (
      <div>
        <Get resource={`/groups/${this.props.groupId.toString()}/members/microsoft.graph.user/?$count=true&$orderby=displayname`} >
          <MemberPerson template="value" />
          <LoadingPerson template="loading" />
        </Get>
      </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `props.dataContext` doesn't have a person property but is the person object itself, try changing your `MyPerson` definition to:

```
const MyPerson = (props: MgtTemplateProps) => {
  const person = props.dataContext;
  return <Person userId={person.userPrincipalName}></Person>;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Is it possible to also have a "loading" template (and maybe an "error" template) as well? I have seen how to achieve this in the standard mgt components, but I can't find any documentation on how to set this up using the React components.

Comment: Do you mean as part of the `Get` component? If so, it would be similar to how the `value` template is defined- just set the `template` prop to `loading` or `error` on the child component.

Comment: Thank you again, Nikola! I managed creating a new object, and sending in the 'loading' template. Worked like a charm :-)

Comment: As you can see in this code, I'm trying to get a number of people using the Get object. I would like to order them by name. I have tried using this resource query, but it does not sort. Do you know what might be wrong? `/groups/${this.props.groupId.toString()}/members/microsoft.graph.user/?$count=true&$orderby=displayname`

Comment: It could be that this particular API doesn't support sorting. In this case, you'd need to use the `default` template (`<MyPerson template="default" />`) in which you'd get access to the full result set, which you can then sort before rendering.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, Waldek! Any chance you can share how I can manage sorting this collection before the rendering takes place? I have updated my initial question with my working example now, so you can easily see my scenario.

Comment: @WaldekMastykarz , do you have any examples on how to work with the default template in my custom template? Thanks.

Comment: @Frank-OveKristiansen, I haven't tried it, but perhaps something like this would work:

- bind the `MemberPerson` to the `default` template (`template="default"`)
- in the `MemberPerson` template, from `props.dataContext` you'd get the whole collection of data retrieved from Graph, sort it and then loop through it yourself to build the HTML to show

Comment: @Frank-OveKristiansen Hi there, i've been playing around with this lately but i am struggling to deploy it without getting: Manifest not found for component id "78b11c7d-7ca8-47cb-a93c-d3beabb519a1" and version "2.0.0" Have you managed to deploy it? could you share your package.json? everything works nicely when i'm in debug and workbench - but i can't seem to make it deployed without the errors.