# Link Person to Delve profile page

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint, spfx, microsoft-graph-toolkit

In my `Person` components in my React application, I would like to add links on the names of the people it renders.
I.e. when the `displayName` is clicked on, the user is sent to the profile page in Delve of the person it clicked on. For example https://contoso-my.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/me.aspx/?mail@contoso.com

I was actually hoping this was a setting on the component or similar, but I see that it's not. Is it possible to achieve this using a template?
I have already set up atemplate, referring to my other thread here: [Working example for Graph Toolkit using SharePoint spfx, React and Get component with template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64573688/working-example-for-graph-toolkit-using-sharepoint-spfx-react-and-get-component/64580710#64580710).

Please advise.

Comment: Short from re-templating the entire component, there isn't currently a way to add a click handler to just the display name. You can still add a click handler to the entire person component. For individual click handlers, I can see us adding `line1Clicked`, `line2Clicked`, etc events. If this sounds like something that would be useful, could you help us by creating an issue on our repo: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-toolkit/issues/new?assignees=&labels=Needs%3A+Triage+%3Amag%3A%2C+feature-request&template=feature_request.md&title= ?

Comment: Thank you Nikola. How would you go about creating a click handler on the entire component then? Will this come in conflict with 'hover' on person-card?

Comment: Great question. One way to add the click handler is to wrap the person component in a div and attach the click handler to that div. It won't affect the hover behavior for the person card.

Comment: Hi Nikola, I tried wrapping an A HREF tag around the Person component. When I click on the Person in the web page, it now takes me to the page specified. But the same happens when I click on anything inside the Person Card as well. 
My code: 

`<div className={styles.memberRow}><a href={cf.GetDelveProfileLink(person.mail, true)} target="_blank">
          <Person userId={person.userPrincipalName} view={cf.GetPersonViewMode(this.props.memberSize)} fetchImage={true} showPresence={true}
            personCardInteraction={PersonCardInteraction.hover} line2Property="mail"></Person></a></div>`

Comment: Hi again @NikolaMetulev, I have now registered a Feature Request on this issue. Please check it out here: [link](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-toolkit/issues/826). Please let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: Thanks @Frank-Ove.