# Microsoft Graph Toolkit - How to loop through Get component result using React and default template

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint, spfx, microsoft-graph-toolkit

Using the `default` template in the Get component, the whole result is returned. When using React Graph Toolkit components, how can I loop through this result set in the template created, and create f.ex. Person components for each result item?

Answer (score 0):

If you're fetching `/user` resource and the result is an array, then the `value` template will be more suitale:

```
const LoadingPerson = (props: MgtTemplateProps) => {
  return <div><Spinner size={SpinnerSize.large} label="Loading members..." /></div>;
};

const MemberPerson = (props: MgtTemplateProps) => {
  const person = props.dataContext;
  return <div>
    <Person userId={person.userPrincipalName} view={PersonViewType.twolines} fetchImage={true} showPresence={true}
      personCardInteraction={PersonCardInteraction.hover} line2Property="mail"></Person>
  </div>;
};

<Get resource="/users" scopes={["User.Read.All"]}>
    <MemberPerson template="value" />
    <LoadingPerson template="loading" />
</Get>
```

[image]

More reference:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/toolkit/get-started/mgt-react

Comment: Thanks! I'm already using the `value` template. But I need to sort the result set before rendering it. How can I achieve this? I have been told to use the `default` template, ref this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64573688/working-example-for-graph-toolkit-using-sharepoint-spfx-react-and-get-component